# conditional check for focus is in textarea or input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, keycode, onkeyup

```
$('body').keyup(function(e)
{
    var code = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;

    switch(code)
    {
        case 8:
        alert('blah');
        break;
    }
});
```

When a user hits backspace, I want the alert to pop up UNLESS the cursor is positioned within a textearea, input, etc.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that `e.target.nodeName` is not `"INPUT"` nor `"TEXTAREA"`, etc.